# UWP Null Reference Exception - Adduplex SDK

Tags: c#, uwp, adduplex

I'm using Adduplex Monetisation SDK after updating my UWP app in Windows Store I get this exception crashing the App, the debuging and release on are working fine on may machine any help please :

```
stowed_exception_system.nullreferenceexception_80004003_youtubevideod.dll!adduplex::interstitialad::_loadadtaskasync_d__59.movenext
```

**Failure details (Stack Trace):**

[image: Stack Trace]

**Edit:**

I've implemented the SDK as suggested on Adduplex documentation from here :
[AdDuplex Interstitial Ad Installation and Usage](https://adduplex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204849091-Windows-10-XAML-AdDuplex-Interstitial-Ad-Installation-and-Usage)

Here is my code:

```
   private async void Adduplex_LoadInterstitial()
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                   async () =>
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           if (adduplexInterstitialAd == null)
                           {
                               InitializeInterstitialAd();
                           }
                           else if (ConnectivityUtil.HasInternetConnection())
                           {
                               await adduplexInterstitialAd.LoadAdAsync();
                           }
                       }
                       catch (Exception){ }
                   });
    }
```

Comment: 1. Why not handle the exception? 2. Show some code because my crystall ball is broken. 3. It doesn't break... did you test it with Release version or it just doesn't break in Debug?

Comment: Both Release and Debug are working fine on my machine, The stack trace provided is from my Windows Store Dashboard, I've implemented the SDK as suggested on Adduplex Website : https://adduplex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204849091-Windows-10-XAML-AdDuplex-Interstitial-Ad-Installation-and-Usage

Comment: @MichalKania please check my edited question, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the problem to AdDuplex.

First of all your stack trace is for the .net native, which makes it useless in debugging of most problems and it seems to be not very useful here too. To make it useful you would need to convert it to stacktrace for your code using .pdb files generated with package, but as Microsoft never made a tool for that, good luck with trying to do it. I think I once saw the 3rd party tool for that that runs from the command prompt but maybe it is pulled from GitHub or I can't find it anymore.

But it seems likely to be a crashing issue inside AdDuplex based on the crash log, so no one can fix it except AdDuplex.